# Como Iterar sobre Datasnapshot corretamente no Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

Estou a 8  dias tentando Pegar do firebase os registros que lá coloquei. Contudo, nunca consigo traze-los corretamente.

--- Android para Firebase

```
   private void initPreencheLista() {
        listCelula.clear();
        novaRef = databaseReference.child( "Celulas" );
        novaRef.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Celula c = new Celula();
                for(DataSnapshot objSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    c = objSnapshot.getValue(Celula.class);
                    cels.add( c.getCelula() );
                }
                arrayAdapterCelula = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CelulasActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cels );
                celulaList.setAdapter( arrayAdapterCelula );
            }
```

Tentei de muitos jeitos fazer isso até usei

```
   for(DataSnapshot objSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                 String a = objSnapshot.child( "Celula" ).getValue(String.class);
                 cels.add( a );
```

Só não posso desistir. To na luta, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei grato.

No primeiro jeito o objSnapshot vem carregado com todo o objeto que chamei. Mas da erro: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type celulas.Celula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como o seu nó está disposto no firebase? Por exemplo, se o seu nó estiver com duas chaves você vai precisar percorrer os dados com dois for. Um para a primeira chave e outro para a segunda chave. Algo mais ou menos assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                
                Log.i("retorno", dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                //Estrutura: Id1, Id2, então são 2 for.

                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dados : ds.getChildren()){
                        Usuario user = dados.getValue(Usuario.class);
                        idUsuario = usuario.getIdUsuario();                           
                        Log.i("Escolhido", "Id: " + idUsuario);

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Eu fiz assim pois preciso de um for apenas. Mas deu erro.      
  `public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot objSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Celula c = objSnapshot.getValue(Celula.class);
                    String celula = c.getCelula();
                    cels.add( celula );` com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type celulas.Celula

Comment: private void initPreencheLista() {
        listCelula.clear();
        novaRef = databaseReference.child( "Celulas" );

Comment: Cara! Fiz de novo como o Iassuli fez dom dois for e funcionou. Nem acredito. Muito obrigado. Eles deveriam por isso na documentação do Firebase. Eu acho incompleto.